doMC R package not working as expected when using system commands inside foreach loop
I'm trying to use the doMC parallel backend to speed up an embarassingly parallel process. The general process works as follows:
-  define parameter grid 
-  foreach combination of parameters in grid: %dopar%
       1. generate parameter depending file using system() command
       2. use a function to process file
       3. use a function, which takes in the processed file to calculate some metric 
       4. combine the results (parameters, metric) into a dataframe

Now, I'm testing this using 4 combinations of parameters, so I registered 4 cores. 1 Itself takes ~15 seconds to run. I tested the code commenting step 3 (using some constant for the metric instead of calculating it), and everything finishes, but in ~1 minute, so I suspect that this isn't running in parallel. My guess is that it isn't doing so since generating the files requires reading a unique file, and I'm guessing this file is being "kidnapped" by one of the cores until it finishes it's task. Strangely, when monitoring this step, all 48 cores go up to 100%, which I have no idea why. How should I work around this issue?
Also, independently, I tested 3, while commenting 1, 2. By itself, 3 takes ~1 minute. So, if things were running in parallel, doing 4 times should also take approimately the same amount of time. Thing is, while monitoring this, I actually see that there are 4/5 tasks running simultaniously for about a minute, but then it reverts to just one, and keeps running indefinitely (20 mins till I gave up). This actually baffles me since I have not even the slightest idea of what could be going on here, so any clarifications or suggestions to see what's happening would be greatly appreaciated.
EDIT
I thought that maybe the function used in step 3 was the issue so I changed it by some other function, but the same problem occured.
Now, If instead of trying to run the foreach loop in parallel with %dopar% I run it sequentially with %do%, things work (as in, the code finishes running).
